# How does a compiler interpret incomplete initialisation lists when initialising a multidimensional array?

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I've got stuck trying to trace back some logic a compiler applies to incomplete multidimensional initialisation lists.
Say there is a `3d` array like this:

```
char list[3][3][3];
```

If I initialise it with a single element like this:

```
char list[3][3][3] = {1}
```

Everything is as expected, the compiler sets `list[0][0][0]` to 1 and the rest elements stay uninitialised holding 0 or some random values.
Things turn into a mess if I try to apply a list like this:

```
char list[3][3][3] = {{1, 2}, 3}
```

I expect an element `list[0][1][0]` to hold the value 3. Instead, it is stored at `list[1][0][0]`. In other words, if specifying a 2-dimensional initialisation list for a 3-dimensional array, instead of switching arrays of the second dimension it switches the outermost ones.

It is also interesting that if I specify an initialisation list like `{3, {1, 2}}`, the compiler gives a warning of excess elements yet still compiles the code, storing `3` and `1` at positions `[0][0][0]` and `[0][0][1]` without storing `2` anywhere (at least I didn't find it).

The question is: *How does a compiler interpret incomplete multidimensional initialisation lists?* I would be glad to get some kind of a review on its logic concerning initialising multidimensional arrays with such kind of initialisation lists.

Comment: @KamilCuk I'll edit to `a compiler` :) I mean generally of course. I used `clang`, now I'll try to do the same with `gcc`. Doubt the result will not be the same

Comment: @KamilCuk Tried `gcc`, the result is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, per Standard, if you initialize any element of a compound, all remaining elements not explicitly assigned are initialized as well as if assigned 0 (i.e. for pointers it is `NULL`, for floats 0.0). This applies recursively, so works for arrays of arrays and structs within structs, etc.

The elements are assigned in memory from lower to higher address where the rightmost index of an array of arrays changes most quickly. So for a[][] the sequence is a[0][0], a[0][1], ... a[1][0], a[1][1], ...

If you leave out braces, things are... slightly complicated. From C99, 6.7.8 Initialization

> 16. Otherwise, the initializer for an object that has aggregate or union type shall be a brace-enclosed list of initializers for the elements or named members.
> 17. Each   brace-enclosed   initializer   list   has   an   associated current   object.   When   no designations are present, subobjects of the current object are initialized in order according to  the  type  of  the  current  object:  array  elements  in  increasing  subscript  order, structure members in declaration order, and the first named member of a union. In contrast, a designation  causes  the  following  initializer  to  begin  initialization  of  the  subobject described  by  the  designator.   Initialization  then  continues  forward  in  order,  beginning with the next subobject after that described by the designator.
> 18. Each  designator  list  begins  its  description  with  the  current  object  associated  with  the closest  surrounding  brace  pair.   Each  item  in  the  designator  list  (in  order)  specifies  a particular  member  of  its  current  object  and  changes  the  current  object  for  the  next designator (if any) to be that member. The current object that results at the end of the designator list is the subobject to be initialized by the following initializer.
> 19. The  initialization  shall  occur  in  initializer  list  order,  each  initializer  provided  for  a particular subobject overriding any previously listed initializer for the same subobject; all subobjects  that  are  not  initialized  explicitly  shall  be  initialized  implicitly  the  same  as objects that have static storage duration.
> 20. If  the  aggregate  or  union  contains  elements  or  members  that  are  aggregates  or  unions, these rules apply recursively to the subaggregates or contained unions.  If the initializer of a subaggregate  or  contained  union  begins  with  a  left  brace,  the  initializers  enclosed  by that  brace  and  its  matching  right  brace  initialize  the  elements  or  members  of  the subaggregate or the contained union.  Otherwise, only enough initializers from the list are taken to account for the elements or members of the subaggregate or the first member of the  contained  union;  any remaining  initializers  are  left  to  initialize  the  next  element  or member of the aggregate of which the current subaggregate or contained union is a part.
> 21. If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a string literal used to initialize an array of known size  than  there  are  elements  in  the  array,  the  remainder  of  the  aggregate  shall  be initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.
> 22. If  an  array  of  unknown  size  is  initialized,  its  size  is  determined  by  the  largest  indexed element  with  an  explicit  initializer.  At the  end  of  its  initializer  list,  the  array  no  longer has incomplete type.

Comment: I think `{1, 2}` being placed at `0 0 0` and `0 0 1` cannot be an array of arrays, it is an array of single elements. Check the addresses of these elements, there is only one byte of difference between them (in accordance with the array `char` type).

Comment: @Kaiyaha You are right, I think I have to meditate a bit :-)